# Importing data from csv file to postgresql table using C# and NPGSQL

Tags: c#, .net, database, npgsql

I am working in a .net mvc web application with using NPGSQL. In my project, I want to update the records in my postgres database using a .csv file. Maybe someone did it? Can someone send sample code? Someone will tell you how to do it?
So far, I have displayed data on my website using C# and NPGSQL.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to insert new rows, you may want to look at [the PostgreSQL COPY feature](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html); this is exposed by Npgsql [via this API](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html#text-copy).

Otherwise you can use a .NET CSV parser and construct UPDATE statements which you can execute manually.